# Use button to go to another Glade GUI, using other Glade GUI, and then get the text of the second GUI entry box

Tags: python, gtk, glade

Good morning everyone, I'm in trouble with Glade. I managed with a button connect to the other glade graphical interface, but I can not get the text inside the entry box of the second GUI. I think have the handlers correct and the id's well defined. Can you tell me what is the problem ?

**This are my GUI's**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJZ35.jpg

I know by doing `[var = builder.get_object("my_entry_id")][1]`, he is not getting anything.
The error is giving me is:

***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/schedule-0.4.3/testando.py", line 186, in apply
    state1 = text_state1.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'***

**This is what i have:**

```
def portManager(button):
   print ("Button Port Manager pressed")
   builder = Gtk.Builder()
   builder.add_from_file("Port_Manager.glade")
   handlers = {
           "action_Apply":apply
   }


   builder.connect_signals(handlers)
   window = builder.get_object("windowPort")
   window.show_all()

   Gtk.main()

def apply(button):
    text_state1 = builder.get_object("state1")
    state1 = text_state1.get_text()
    print(state1) 
    print ("Port Aplied!")




#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# GUI (Graphical User Interface)
builder = Gtk.Builder()                                                                                                                                  # Creates GUI
builder.add_from_file("Wi_Green_Sheddule_v1.glade")                                                                                                      # Gets GUI   
handlers = {                                                                                                                                             # Associates GUI to functions Python                  
      "action_clear": clear,                                                                                                                             # Action of Button Clear defined      
      "action_start": action_start,                                                                                                                      # Action of Button Start defined   
      "save_hours": save_hours,                                                                                                                          # Action of Button Save defined      
      "delete_file": delete_file,                                                                                                                         # Action of Button Delete defined
      "portManager": portManager
   }

builder.connect_signals(handlers)                                                                                                                        # Connects GUI handlers to functions
window = builder.get_object("window")                                                                                                                    # Gets the inside of GUI         
window.show_all()                                                       

Gtk.main()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should make a new class to work with the second UI.

Comment: I dont know how can i do it with another class. Im trying. Thanks for the reply